# How to reply to a comment asking you to write code?

Tags: discussion, comments

So I've been answering a few questions on SO, and I've also been replying to questions in comments - usually when I do the latter, I am suggesting a code optimisation or a solution that literally only may take up 1-3 lines.

This time I was asked to write the code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852597/how-to-write-and-read-and-replace-from-atext-file) particular question;

> Thanks @AlexM for the reply ,was asking if u could write the code for me as you suggested thanks

As shown, they're replying to a comment I posted. So how do I go about replying to that comment? Should I say `No` and specify a reason or actually answer it, in comments?

Comment: Just updated the link to your question as I noticed the comment in the question myself.

Comment: If you don't want to provide more information, then you are not obliged to reply to a comment. If you have (or want to provide) a full solution then you might want to consider writing an answer (and not a comment).

Comment: @honk the former has been what I've been doing thus far. However, I feel that it's rather impolite to do so - especially if I reply to another comment on that same question but not to them, essentially ignoring them...

Comment: You invest your time on SO for free. Nobody can expect you to be here 24/7 and reply to every comment addressed to you. I don't think that you would appear to be impolite if you don't reply. And if the OP thinks it anyway, then the OP might have a wrong impression on what SO is for.

Comment: @AlexM. imo for those code request, I check 2 things. **1/. Is the question worthy?** ( op show time investisment in the question, op is willing to edit his question to make it more accurate, op is nice, op has the informed badge) if he fails More than 2 of those critera he has an automatique downvote .

Comment: **2/. Do I have something usefull to say?** If I don't see How writting the code could help explaining a common mistake or a specific issue. If I can write the code but don't have the level to explain why I do it that way. if I dont have what it takes to make a relatively good answer on the question. I pass. *PS: This is more about answering than code writing. but for them it's the same. A valid answer must be a full code.*

Comment: The alternative I'd take in that case would be "I'm not here to do your job/project for you, but to help you get it running. So when you get stuck along the way at some point, post the code that's not working for you and how's it failing, and we'll get it fixed in no time", while having a clear "he's not gonna do it" / "i'll help out if (s)he does it" expectation.

Comment: No. <--- empy space --->

Comment: In addition to what Pierre said, you might also consider whether the OP is willing to listen, even if you do have something useful to say. They replied to someone who left 2 comments requesting clarification with, "so how am i supposed to do it thanks". Trying to help someone who refuses to even acknowledge requests for more information never ends well.

Comment: If you're a 10k plus user, you can see one way to deal with it at [Array wraparound in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882995/array-wrap-around-in-c).  It's not necessarily the best, but the end result — an unsatisfactory question where no effort was made to solve a simple problem is no longer visible — is one solution.  The OP deleted the post while I was typing up another explanation, which was more than they deserved.

Comment: Don't worry too much about being "impolite". The more "polite" everyone is, the higher the expectations become for everyone else and soon we're all forced to walk on eggshells because "that's the site culture". As long as you are not insulting them, it's fine to give a direct refusal.

Comment: It depends. If you _want_ to write an answer and you feel that it would be of genuine help to the OP & future readers, then go ahead and answer it. However, as S. L. Barth says, spoon-feeding isn't helpful in the long run. It seems pretty clear to me that the OP of the linked question is a [help vampire](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm) and feeding HVs is counter-productive.

Comment: I simply inform them that nobody is obliged to answer their question, and leave it as that.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You don't have to respond at all. But if you do, "No" is perfectly acceptable.

You might want to phrase it more politely than just "no", of course. The asker of that question has been given quite a few tips in the comments, and if they're not going to implement these themselves, they'll never learn. A good teacher doesn't spoon-feed, but instead encourages the student to try for themselves.

So - I'd say "I suggest you try this for yourself first. Programming is best learnt by doing. Good luck!" Or some variation of that. You *could* also tell them to come back if they get stuck, but I've learnt not to encourage that. If they really need help, they will come back anyway. If they don't - so much the better.

Comment: A more blunt way would be saying "*StackOverflow is not a free coding service. We happily help you with problems in your code, but if you want it written for you I suggest to hire a programmer*". This might not apply to every case, but usually when the OP doesn't show any effort and posts no code.

Comment: How is just saying "no" impolite?

Comment: @Braiam "More politely than" does not necessarily mean that "No" is impolite, similarly to how "faster than" does not necessarily mean that a "speeding bullet" is slow.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Oh I really really like that analogy.

Comment: Then, there's no need to say "You might want to phrase it more politely than just "no"" @AndrewMorton.

Comment: The question as I read it, was how to decline the request gracefully. Just "no" is blunt. If I chose the blunt way to respond (and _sometimes_ that is the best way to get the message across) I'd go with @Bergi's wording.

Comment: @Braiam A single word response to any question, at least to me, is not polite. We're humans, not robots. A single word response is curt, blunt, or otherwise unfriendly. It's not incorrect, but if you're looking to be polite, be a little more verbose.

Comment: I can imagine the conversation taking place in person and a simple 'no' being put either very politely or very impolitely.  Bereft of any other contextual cues, a simple written 'no' seems overly terse.

Answer (score 14):

I believe the best option is not to reply at all - neither comment nor update answer.

I only see two outcomes from answering such request - "you are complete @##$#." comments (flag-able, but will ruin your day if you are not used to it) or completely ignore your reply and continue nagging (at some point you'll get pissed off and reply something you regret later).

[Thumper - If you can't say something nice, don't say nothing at all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I71cY9Ysy5U)

Answer (score -17):

Users like that who add nothing to the site and are not willing to do anything to help themselves, are best just down voted.   Looking at their other questions they are close to a question ban.   But only down vote 1 other questions of their, as otherwise the automatic vote checking script will undo the good work of your down votes.

Also consider if any of their other questions should have a close vote for being unclear or too board....

Comment: Please don't encourage people to vote based on the user posting. The content is what should be voted on, regardless of the one doing the posting.

Comment: Intentionally trying to get someone question banned is the opposite of what you should be trying to do. If you notice a pattern of bad questions, leave a comment on how they can improve. If they continue to post low quality questions and get question banned, it needs to be entirely because of their own actions, not yours.

Comment: @TinyGiant I totally agree that a question should be responded to on its own merits. However, if you suspect that the OP is a help vampire there's nothing wrong with looking at their other questions / comments to confirm that suspicion before deciding on how to respond to them. OTOH, I'm not saying that all questions from HVs deserve to be downvoted, but they often are, due to insufficient research, and generally deserve close-votes due to lack of MCVE.

Comment: @TinyGiant, if you look at his other questions, you will see there is no need to consider the user before deciding that most (maybe all) of them should be downvoted, as SO would be better without them.

Comment: @IanRingrose but you still don't purposefully go through them and downvote them... That's wrong in many ways and should really only be downvoted as we come across them :/